# Register for Bootstrap-4 events using Angular-4 - Replace menu heading while menu is open

Tags: angular, events, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I have some nice Bootstrap code here.

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="my-dropdown-id">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" (click)="cogWheelClick()">
     <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-md-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

What I need to do now is to replace the cog-wheel on the menu heading when the user clicks on it.
Replace the line

```
<i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

by

```
<i class=\"fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw\"></i>
```

But only if the dropdown setting is open.
There are some nice Bootstrap events to do so.
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#events

But as much as I try, I can't get it to run...
I usually never get this event even thought i registered for it.
What I've already tried is registering for my-dropdown-id and on another approach on dropdown01.

I already tried using the click event (as seen above). But this isn't an acceptable result, as the menu is usually closed without a click event :-).

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried ngx-bootstrap? It's an angular wrapper around bootstrap 4 that might expose all of the events to you the angular way.

Comment: This is how I have currently installed it. I'll have a look on ngx-bootstrap.
$ npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 font-awesome
https://alligator.io/angular/ng-bootstrap/